# MySql : finding MAX of SUM values?

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I would like to find out the highest quantity of the item of each category.

I have a table named "products" as shown below :

```
+----------+-------+-----+
| Category | Item  | Qty |
+----------+-------+-----+
| A        | A100  |  15 |
| A        | A100  |   7 |
| A        | A101  |   3 |
| A        | A101  |   9 |
| B        | B100  |   6 |
| B        | B100  |   7 |
| B        | B101  |   8 |
| B        | B101  |  13 |
+----------+-------+-----+
```

After I execute the query

```
SELECT Category, Item, SUM(Qty) as Quantity FROM products GROUP BY Category,Item;
```

I got the results as below

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| Category | Item  | Quantity |
+----------+-------+----------+
| A        | A100  |       22 |
| A        | A101  |       12 |
| B        | B100  |       13 |
| B        | B101  |       21 |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

Now I want to find the highest quantity of the item in each category, which I want to have my output as follows :

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| Category | Item  | Quantity |
+----------+-------+----------+
| A        | A100  |       22 |
| B        | B101  |       21 |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

how can I do that? I have tried the query below but I only got 'OK' as the result without giving me any output table.

```
select Category, Item, max(Qty) as Quantity from products group by OD_type  having Quantity = (select sum(Qty) from products group by Item);
```

How can I get my desired output as shown in the table above? 
I am sorry if this is not a good question or my question is not clear enough.
Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use it as subquery , in case there are two items with same max value, you will get only one of them.

```
SELECT Category, Item, Max(Quantity) as MaxVal
FROM
(
SELECT Category, Item, SUM(Qty) as Quantity 
FROM products 
GROUP BY Category,Item
) T
GROUP BY Category
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be easier to use a `view` or a `common-table-expression` (if `mysql` would support it).

```
SELECT t.category, t.item, t.quantity
FROM (
    SELECT Category, Item, SUM(Qty) Quantity 
    FROM products 
    GROUP BY Category, Item
  ) t JOIN (
    SELECT category, max(quantity) Quantity
    FROM (
      SELECT Category, Item, SUM(Qty) Quantity 
      FROM products 
      GROUP BY Category,Item
    ) t
    GROUP BY category
  ) t2 ON t.Category = t2.Category and t.quantity = t2.quantity
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae3d3/4)

The basic idea is to get the `sum` grouped by each category and item, then to get the `max(sum)` by each category, and then `join` back to the original `sum` query...

Answer (score 0):

This looks ugly and I'm seeing if mysql has a better way... but I believe it works...

```
SELECT A.category, A.Item, A.Quantity
FROM (SELECT Category, Item, SUM(Qty) as Quantity 
      FROM products 
      GROUP BY Category,Item) A
INNER JOIN (Select Max(B.quantity) Quantity, B.Category 
            FROM 
              (SELECT Category, SUM(Qty) as Quantity 
               FROM products 
               GROUP BY Category, Item) B
            GROUP BY Category) C
  ON A.Category=C.Category
 and A.Quantity = C.Quantity
```

I want to use a window set but it appears mysql doesn't support them.  And since we have to aggregate the data first before we can get the max, the inner select is necessary.. and I wanted to use a CTE to improve readability, but MySQL doesn't support them either...

I would probably create tables A, B as a View and call the view to make this easier to read long run.

Comment: Nope, not finding a better way.